# Batch file to split text file into multiple files in same directory on Win Svr 2012 using NO 3rd Party Apps

Tags: batch-file, split, text-files, move, delete-file

I am hoping the wonderful experts here can assist me with my problem.  I have found this site extremely useful in the past in solving other issues I have had but I have searched this site and tried all the answers similar to my problem but cant seem to get any of them to work for this particular problem. I am not a coder but have dabbled with other code and got them to work for other issues.

I need to split a text file containing keywords(1 kw per line, no blank lines) into multiple text files within the same directory, each with 300 lines (except last text file if total input lines not exactly divisible by 300). The input file will NEVER be larger than 100MB.

Ideally, I then need the input file deleted once it has been split and all split text files moved to another directory (there are no other text files to worry about in the original directory)
I need it to be a bat file or vbs script called via bat file.

**input file:**

- keyword-file.txt

**output files:**

- keyword-file_1.txt (300 lines)
- keyword-file_2.txt (300 lines)
- keyword-file_3.txt (300 lines)
- etc

**To clarify requirements the above:**

1. Split input text file (<100MB) into smaller text files, each with 300 lines
2. Delete input text file
3. Move all split text files to another specified directory

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

For the splitting, perhaps something like this will do:

```bat
@Echo Off
Setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "inFile=keyword-file.txt"
Set "nLines=300"

If Not Exist "%inFile%" GoTo :EOF
For %%A In ("%inFile%") Do Set "fName=%%~nA"&Set "fExt=%%~xA"

Set "count=0"
For /F %%A In ('Find /C /V ""^<"%inFile%"') Do Set "fLines=%%A"

(For /L %%A In (1 1 %fLines%) Do (Set/P "data="
    Set/A "file=(count/%nLines%)+1", "count+=1"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    (Echo=!data!)>>"%fName%_!file!%fExt%"
    EndLocal))<"%inFile%"

EndLocal
GoTo :EOF
```

*I'll leave the deletion and move commands to you…*

Comment: Since you are appending to the `%fname%_!files!%fext%` I'd reset them first.

Comment: I didn't see any point @LotPings, it was stipulated that no other text files existed in that directory.