# Batch split text file by number of lines

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I have looked all over and cant find a simple windows batch script to split a text file by number of lines.

I have a .txt file with about 150,000 lines

im trying to make a batch that will split the text file every 1000 lines.

I have also tried using Gsplit with no success

If you can find a similar question, please link me

thanks so much in advance.

I think finding an answer to this question will be helpful for other users and people on google

Comment: There appears to be a similar type question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389673/batch-file-to-split-text-file-into-multiple-files-in-same-directory-on-win-svr-2/44390846#44390846)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a `for` loop and a counter.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Ensure that the user passed the file to the script
if "%~1"=="" (
    echo Please provide a file to process. You can drag the file onto the script.
    exit /b
)

set "split_at=1000"
set "input_file_name=%~1"
set "output_file_base_name=%~n1"
set "split_count=1"
set "line_count=1"

:: Move to the directory where the file is
pushd %~dp1

for /f "delims=" %%A in (%input_file_name%) do (
    >>%output_file_base_name%.!split_count! echo(%%A
    set /a line_count+=1

    REM If we've reached the split_number, roll the log over
    if !line_count! gtr %split_at% (
        set line_count=1
        set /a split_count+=1
    )
)

popd
```

Comment: Starting with line_count zero and doing a modulus calculation in one set /a seems easier to me. `set /a "line_count+=1,split_count=line_count %% split_at"` before the output reduces overhead.